# how can I autoload session library once in CI4 and access every where like CI3

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4.1 for my project. I had worked on CI3 before.
I want to load the **session** library once in the project and access it everywhere like we use in CI3 autoload.php.

I have added `$this->session = \Config\Services::session();` code in BaseController, but I can not use it in Models.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'super object' in CI4 as there was in CI3; you shouldn't expect anything to be passed around magically. If you need something in your Model that exists in your Controller, either pass it in as a parameter or make a new one in the Model itself.